# IBM Cloud Code Risk Analyser preventing test of undeployed code

Tags: ibm-cloud, toolchain

I use a Node-RED instance in IBM Cloud to test new and updated code before publishing, but the code risk analyser that makes up the toolchain pipeline prevents anything that is not already published from being used.

```
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-node-watson.git
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-06-17T07_53_14_536Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --no-audit --no-update-notifier --no-fund --production' returned a non-zero code: 254
Error running docker build: unable to build Docker image
FAILED
```

This occurs on all dependencies, that I attempt to load from GitHub as opposed from NPM.

The only change I have made is via the Web IDE to `package.json`, then allowing the toolchain to kick in and rebuild, where this works

```
"node-red-node-watson": "0.10.3",
```

and this doesn't

```
"node-red-node-watson": "https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-node-watson.git#master",
```

Comment: It seems like another issue. What about the file not found?

Comment: That is a good point. I don't know what file its looking for. This is happening on all dependencies where I attempt to pull from GitHub rather than NPM.

Comment: add the commands you are using

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. This is a newly created instance of node-red, and the only change I made was in `package.json`. The edits have been made using the  web ide as part of the toolchain.